# Is there a RubyMine equivalent of TextMate's "Reveal in Project" shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

One of TextMate's many nice features is that you can type Ctrl+Cmd+R to show the file with current focus in the navigation sidebar (opening up parent folders as necessary). I haven't been able to find this feature in the much more heavyweight RubyMine (based on IntelliJ). Does it exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`View` | `Select In` | `Project`. Or enable the `Autoscroll from Source` option for the Project View.

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions of RubyMine (4.0+) this feature is under the `Navigate`|`Select In...`|`Project View` menu.